# calling a function inside class

Tags: python, function, class, call

How I can call a function inside class like this code? I tried, but I can not... The idea is: I want update the other function inside de class, than I use this code, without sucess: app=MyApp()                  app.build.last1.text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S \n")

How I do it?

(...)

```
class PL1_detect(Button):

    def update(self, dt):
                global ModoPisca
                global t
                global ModoPisca2
                global last2


                #ModoPisca=0
                def tpisca():
                    conta=0
                    global estado_PTT1
                    ##clock(self, dt)
                    app=MyApp()
                    app.build.last1.text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S \n")
                   #(here the problem: HOW I CAN CALL FUNCTION OF CLASS
```

MYAPP(APP) ????

(...)

```
class MyApp(App):   


    def build(self):


                layout = FloatLayout(size=(800, 600))
        # Make the background gray:
        with layout.canvas.before:
            Color(.2,.2,.2,1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=(800,600), pos=layout.pos)


                wimg = Image(source='logo.png', pos=(0,180))

        last1=Label(text=(" "), pos=(-330, -110), font_size='17sp', bold=0)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please format your code. Python is sensitive to formatting, as are python programmers.

Answer (score -1):

You can create object for that class 
M=Myapp()
M.build() will help in calling that function.

Try this for your scenario

```
class A():
    def funct1(self):
        sample="hi"

class B():
    def func2(self):
        A.sample="hello"
        print A.sample

a=A()
a.funct1()
b=B()
b.func2()
```

Output:
hello

Comment: The idea is: I want update the other function inside de class, than I use this code, without sucess: app=MyApp()                  app.build.last1.text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S \n")

How I do it?

Comment: is both the class in same file ?

Comment: If it is in the same file , Try calling it with the classname itself, instead of object. Myapp.build.last1.text. Also place that Myapp class above the calling class .

Comment: yes it is in the same file...I tried to call as you said, without sucessful... I get this error:  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'last1'

Comment: That above code works for me, I assume you try to set the last1 text value variable in one class from the other class. Try that using classname once.

Comment: yes otherwise it wont be able to recognize that class .

Comment: I just tried put Myapp class above, and I get this error:  NameError: global name 'PL1_detect' is not defined

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 236, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 800, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "main.py", line 113, in build
     inputDisplay1 = PL1_detect(text="RX", size_hint=(.1, .1), pos=(25, 200))
 NameError: global name 'PL1_detect' is not defined

Comment: Okay. I don't see that line in the original question you have asked, It seems you are refering to PL1_detect in your build function. But for me even the order is that issue with the code I have pasted. Which version of python you are using ?

Comment: the version is: Python 2.7.13